# Schedule job for SQL

Tags: sql, web-crawler, scheduled-tasks

I have a list of `urls` which I need to crawl, so I can index the pages and add them to my `searchindex.db`

```
urls = ['http://consequenceofsound.net/', 'http://www.tinymixtapes.com/', 'https://www.residentadvisor.net/']
```

this is how I've initialized my crawler class:

```
class crawler:
    # Initialize the crawler with the name of database
    def __init__(self,dbname):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)

    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()

    def dbcommit(self):
        self.con.commit()
```

this is the crawling method:

```
def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):

            (...)
            #code here that opens and adds links to database    
            (...)       

            self.dbcommit() 

            pages=newpages
```

here I instantiate my `crawler class`:

```
crawler=crawler('searchindex.db')

pagelist = url[0]

crawler.crawl(pagelist)
```

how do I schedule `url crawling` and indexing of pages, so that each crawling indexing process resumes after the last one is finished or interrupted by any reason?

Comment: Is Linux's `crontab` an option?

Comment: Sorry, not part of my database :-(.